# How can I convert those two loops using map and filter?

Tags: python

I try to write this code using the map and filter built-in functions. How can I do it?

```
for elem in courses_dict:
    for ele in types:
            for element in types[ele]:
                if elem==element:
                    courses_dict[elem]+=factors[ele]
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert this into map and filter? The result would be an unreadable behemoth

Comment: it's not correct to use types[ele]...
by doing "for ele in types", ele is already an item of your list types, not the index of an element of the list.

Comment: that's a lot of `element` shortcut-names in the same data block. It could be easier (even for you!) to be forced to use more specific names ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified code from your question that assumes that `types` is a mapping: `type_id` -> `types`:

```
for course_id in courses_dict:
    for type_id, type_values in types.items(): # assume `types` is a mapping
        for type in type_values:
            if course_id == type:
               courses_dict[course_id] += factors[type_id]
```

You could make the inner loop implicit:

```
for course_id in courses_dict:
    for type_id, type_values in types.items(): # assume `types` is a mapping
        count = type_values.count(course_id) # assume `.count` is present
        if count: # course_id in type_values
           courses_dict[course_id] += count*factors[type_id]
```

It `type_values` has `.count()` method e.g., it is a list.

The explicit loops are fine as is. If you want to see how it can be written using `map`, `filter` for academic reasons:

```
from collection import deque
from itertools import product, starmap

pairs = product(courses_dict, types)
# course_id == p[0] and type_id == p[1]
triples = map(lambda p: (types[p[1]].count(p[0]),) + p, pairs)
triples = filter(lambda t: t[0], triples) # count == t[0]

def increment(count, course_id, type_id):
    courses_dict[course_id] += count * factors[type_id] 

deque(starmap(increment, triples), maxlen=0) # "consume" recipe from itertools
```

If I'd known what your input values: `courses_dict`, `types`, `factors` contain; better more concrete names could be used instead of the above abstract one. But it would still be ugly.